# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet with name <name>

Tags: spring

Getting the error with following Spring Application Annotation configuration:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<!-- Provide support for component scanning -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />

<!--Provide support for conversion, formatting and validation -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

**Controller Class**

```
package com.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
@Controller()
public class AppController {
@RequestMapping("/")
public String display() {
    return "welcome";
}
}
```

**And** **POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>tut.spring.com</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringMVC</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>SpringMVCApp</name>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

All configuration seems fine to me. But still getting this **ERROR**:

**In Console :**

```
    org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

**In Browser :**

```
 HTTP Status 404 - 


type Status report

message 

description The requested resource is not available.


Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M1
```

**URL being hit :**

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/
```

Please point out to what could be wrong here! Have I imported all the required libraries in POM? and if entries are correct in **spring-servlet.xml**?

Thanks

Comment: Point your request to the value of `<servlet-name>` instead of `<displayName>`.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz You mean like **http://localhost:8080/spring**. But "SpringMVC" is the context on Tomcat server. Still it shows same error!

Comment: Do you have a view (jsp/html) with name - "welcome" mapped?. As 404 yields to a conclusion that you are trying to get a resource which doesnt exist.

Comment: @AjayKumar yes. In my WEB-INF folder I have welcome.html file

Comment: Try adding jstl-1.2.jar dependency then.

Comment: Sill the same error

Comment: How is your app deployed? what's the name of the war? That's probably the tomcat context unless you named the war as ROOT.war

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I am using Eclipse to run Project on Tomcat. "SpringMVC" is the context on Tomcat.